# How to resize a W2003Srv basic partition in Vmvare player

Tags: windows-server-2003, vmware-player, ntfs

### Environment

I have Windows 2003 server (XP)

- Installed as virtual machine using Vmware Player 4.0.2
- Primary partition is, as usual, C:-volume, where Windows is installed.
- Partition type is basic, which cannot be resized with windows tools.

  - I don't want to convert the partition type to dynamic (can be laborious).

### Question: What do I need to do to increase the size of C:-volume?

Comment: If you're going to post a Q/A in a single post, the correct procedure is to post a question and answer it yourself with the answer. Otherwise this "question" will just sit around forever in the un-answered list.

Comment: Seems that I can't answer my own question quite yet. When I tried to post an answer, I got this message: _Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead._ I'll add my answer to the question section for now, and I'll add the answer later.

Comment: @Ciove, don't forget to approve your answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Download [SystemRescueCd](http://www.sysresccd.org/Download) ISO-image.

### In Vmware player, when the virtual Windows 2003 server is not running:

- increase the size of your disk: Virtual Machine / Virtual Machine settings / Hardware / Hard Disk / Utilities / Expand.
- Change CD-drive to use the SystemRescueCd ISO-imagefile: Virtual Machine / Virtual Machine settings / Hardware / CD/DVD(IDE) / Use ISO image file / [browse to get the path to ISO-imagefile]
- Edit your [computername].vmx -file (with notepad or similar), add this line:

  ```
  bios.bootDelay = "10000"
  ```

### Start the virtual Windows 2003 server with [SystemRescueCd](http://www.sysresccd.org/Download)

- In virtual machine window hit the **ESC** -key (this may need some trickery: make sure the focus is in the virtual machine window, type Ctrl+G or click in the center of the window, when it goes black)
- In Boot menu choose CD-ROM Drive
- When SystemRescueCd asks for boot options choose default (first option).
- When SystemRescueCd asks for keyboard language, type the number next to your keyboard language.
- When SystemRescueCd has started type **wizard** (and hit **Enter**-key).

  - When wizard asks for graphic environment hit **Enter**.
- When graphical desktop with Terminal window has opened type **gparted** (+**Enter**) in terminal window.
- In gparted -window:

  - Wait for gparted to find partitions.
  - If the partition you need to change is not visible, click Gparted -menu and choose Devices
  - Click partition and click Partition -menu and Resize/Move.
  - In Resize/Move -window use slide control to resize your volume and click Resize/Move -button.
  - Back in gparted -window click **green tick** -icon to apply changes.
  - Close gparted -window.
- In terminal window type **shutdown now** (+**Enter**).
- Wait for "... or type Control-D to continue..." -text to appear.
- In virtual machine window (type Ctrl+Alt to shift focus) click Virtual Machine / Power / Power off.